# When it's three ayem

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following quote is from a book that teaches assembly language. My question is about the "when it's three ayem".

> Assembly-time warnings are the assembler acting as experienced
>   consultant, and hinting that something in your source code is a little
>   dicey. This something may not be serious enough to cause the assembler
>   to stop assembling the file, but it may be serious enough for you to
>   take note and investigate. For example, NASM will flag a warning if
>   you define a named label but put no instruction after it. That may not
>   be an error, but it’s probably an omission on your part, and you
>   should take a close look at that line and try to remember what you
>   were thinking when you wrote it. (This may not always be easy, **when
>   it’s three ayem** or three weeks after you originally wrote the line in
>   question.)

From what I have gathered from Google I suppose that "three ayem" is slang for "three a.m.", and that here in the context it means "when it's late in the day (and you thus might have problems concentrating)". Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. "Ayem" is a phonetic representation of "AM".  Writing it to mean "morning" is, according to *Variety* magazine, its own invention. There are many others. *Variety* is a famous American show business magazine. It calls the vocabulary thus created "slanguage":

> ayem — A Variety coinage meaning morning (a.m.); “Barbara Walters is
>   producing a new ayem skein for ABC.”

[Variety slanguage A-Z](https://variety.com/static-pages/slanguage-dictionary/)

> Almost from its launch in 1905, Variety has used its own, distinctive
>   slanguage in headlines and stories, words like ankle, which refers to
>   someone leaving (say, walking away from) a job, or whammo, which
>   refers to something terrific, especially box office performance. In
>   part it was a device to fit long words into small headlines, but it
>   was also to create a clubby feel among the paper’s entertainment
>   industry readers. People in the business understood thrush; those
>   outside the business, well, they weren’t Variety’s target readers
>   anyway.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed this specific origin; it reminds me a bit of the words coined by MAD Magazine. Thanks for supplying the background.

Comment: I had never heard of 'ayem' until today.